# How to put textures in one file (power of 2)

Tags: graphics, textures

I want to create big texture which is power of 2 and put in this file a lot of smaller textures.
You know, I have several textures which are not power of 2 so I cant load them to my program. I have to put them in one file (512x512 for example).

Do you know any program which can do it for me automaticly?
Is there any limit of size of texture? Can I use for example 8192x8192 file? Or I have to use few smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is *texture atlas*.

The maximum texture size is GPU-dependent, 8k is fine on newer cards. Such a texture consumes, however, a vast amount of VRAM (and it gets worse if you count in MIPs). So it might be better to use several smaller textures and have only those in (hot) VRAM which you really need.

Comment: Hmm...An iPhone - I shouldn't create textures biggest than 1024, should I?

Comment: Oh, I was talking of desktop/workstation GPUs. For OpenGl (ES) `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` gives you the maximum texture size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are several applications that can help you pack images into a texture atlas. [Zwoptex](http://www.zwoptexapp.com/) has both a free Flash version and a commercial Mac app. [TexturePacker](http://texturepacker.com/) has a Mac and Windows app, and a command line version, some features are free and some require a paid license. These output the packed images into a single image and an associated data file with coordinates on the location of the packed images. They also can trim the transparent regions from around any given image, if any, saving even more space.

There are some more tools, some open source, listed in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278365/sprite-sheet-generator-for-iphone).

The advantages of packing into one texture are potential space saving, but also fewer OpenGL state changes when drawing several images from the texture, for better performance.