# Sprite sheet generator for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, 2d, sprite

Until now I have been making my own 1024*1024 sprite sheets by placing the images in an 64 x 64 grid to help to identify easily the position and size of each sprite.

Needless to say, it works but i'm wasting a lot of space.

Is there any  kind of tool to help me take separate sprites in .png format and generate sprite sheets of any dessired size with them ?. even better if it also generates a file with information about size and coordinates of each sprite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read about Zwoptex in Michael Daley's book *Learn iOS Game Programming*.

http://zwoptexapp.com

Answer (score 2):

Is something like `CATiledLayer` what you need? I does not contain info about each tile, but it is the way maps and large zoom functionality is usually implemented.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number Ruby implementations on [github](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=ruby&q=sprite&repo=&langOverride=&x=18&y=17&start_value=1). While they generate CSS and or HTML, it would be possible to take these one stage further and convert it into an XML file. Would make a nice little tool...

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442299/) a simple texture packer in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sprite Master](http://www.mobinodo.com/spritemaster) to do this. It's trimming feature allows you to use minimal space for your sprite sheet. It also exports coordinate data for your sprite sheet in different formats (Generic XML, Cocos2D, Corona, LibGDX, Sparrow, CSS Export)

Answer (score 0):

There is also texturepacker from codeandweb.com

http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker